# AOSP build: Replace existing AOSP module with a custom one

Tags: android-source, android-soong

I want to replace an already existing module in an AOSP whose build script file is written in `Android.bp` and added to the build process via some `*.mk` file, e.g.:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-service
```

with my module, the build script of which is also written in Soong Blueprint, and also added to the build process via the `*.mk` file, e.g:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += vendor.my.vehicle@2.0-service
```

It seems that this can be done with `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES`, but in this case I need to rewrite my module's build script from `Android.bp` to `Android.mk`.

So, **question**: is the only existing way to do this via rewriting the module's `Android.bp` build script to `Android.mk` (using `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES`) or can it be done with another, more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Soong Blueprint has the ability to do this using the `overrides` property, for example from `Android.bp`:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "vendor.my.vehicle@2.0-service",
    overrides: ["android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-service"],
    ...
}
```